# R - for loop only gives the last interaction result

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to save the results of all interactions, but `for loop` only gives me the result of last interaction. Just like this:

```
l <- list(a = c(1, 3, 5), b = c(4, 8), c = 2)

df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  
  s <- data.frame(name = names(l[i]),
                  value = mean(l[[i]]))
  
  out <- rbind(df, s)
}
```

This code returns this:

[image]

I need to something like this:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `out` variable only contains the result of the last iteration since `out` is overriden in every iteration of the loop.

Replace `out` by `df` like so, your expected result will be in the `df` variable:

```
l <- list(a = c(1, 3, 5), b = c(4, 8), c = 2)
df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  s <- data.frame(name = names(l[i]),
                  value = mean(l[[i]]))
  df <- rbind(df, s)
}
df
```